# Отличие матрицы от вектора векторов

Tags: c++, c, матрицы, терминология, векторы

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем отличие матрицы от вектора векторов?

Comment: А вам с какой точки зрения? Вообще, матрица по своей сути ближе всего к двумерному массиву - она прямоугольная, а вектор векторов может содержать векторы разной длины, из-за чего не каждый такой объект будет матрицей.

Comment: Кроме того что матрица прямоугольна, только семантически. Примерно так же как RGBA отличается от XYZW-вектора и XYZW-скаляра.

Comment: Если в смысле языка (c/c++), то в матрице **все элементы расположены в памяти плотно**, за последним элементом строки сразу находится первый элемент следующей строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала : слово матрица это математическое понятие.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> Ма́трица — математический объект, записываемый в виде прямоугольной таблицы элементов кольца или поля (например, целых, действительных или комплексных чисел), который представляет собой совокупность строк и столбцов, на пересечении которых находятся его элементы. Количество строк и столбцов задает размер матрицы.

В языке Си изначально под матрицей представляли массив всех её элементов, упорядоченных вместе как один большой массив. И называется это N-мерный массив.

стандарт показывает трёхмерный массив :

> EXAMPLE 6 The declaration
>
> ```
> short q[4][3][2] = {
>   { 1 },
>   { 2, 3 },
>   { 4, 5, 6 }
> };
> ```
>
> contains an incompletely but consistently bracketed initialization. It defines a three-dimensional array object: q[0][0][0] is 1, q[1][0][0] is 2, q[1][0][1] is 3, and 4, 5, and 6 initialize q[2][0][0], q[2][0][1], and q[2][1][0], respectively; all the rest are zero. The initializer for q[0][0] does not begin with a left brace, so up to six items from the current list may be used. There is only one, so the values for the remaining five elements are initialized with zero. Likewise, the initializers for q[1][0] and q[2][0] do not begin with a left brace, so each uses up to six items, initializing their respective two-dimensional subaggregates. If there had been more than six items in any of the lists, a diagnostic message would have been issued. The same initialization result could have been achieved by:
>
> ```
> short q[4][3][2] = {
>   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   4, 5, 6
> };
> ```
>
> or by:
>
> ```
> short q[4][3][2] = {
>   {
>     { 1 },
>   },
>   {
>     { 2, 3 },
>   },
>   {
>     { 4, 5 },
>     { 6 },
>   }
> };
> ```

Во втором примере видно что элементы трёхмерного массива расположены подряд и рядом. Доступ к полям компилятор образует такой :

```
int m[4][3][2];
& m[i][j][k] == & m[0][0][0] +  i*2*3 + j*2 + k
```

Но из-за отсутствия в стандарте чёткого способа передавать в функцию массивы неопределённых размеров, у которых формула доступа к полям происходит используя размерность матрицы, стали использовать вектор векторов.

```
// Такое можно назвать как дерево с большим количеством ветвей
// Трёхмерный вектор векторов
int * * * m3 ;
// Одна из ветвей указывает на двумерный вектор векторов
int * * m3i = m3 [ i ] ;
// Дальше указывает на одномерный вектор
int * m3ij = m3i [ j ]  /* == m3 [ i ] [ j ] */ ;
// Теперь это элемент трёхмерного вектора векторов
int m3ijk = m3ij [ k ] /* == m3i [ j ] [ k ] 
                          == m3  [ i ] [ j ] [ k ]  */ ;
```

У этих векторов формула доступа к элементам совсем другая. Происходит выбор элемента главного вектора, в которой находиться указатель. Этот указатель указывает на другую N-1 матрицу, и дальше рекурсивно находиться элемент.

Так как у компилятора нет необходимости знать все размерности вектора векторов получается удобство передачи к функциям только одного указателя. А как передать размерность программист сам придумывает. Главное отличие это большая нагрузка на диспетчер памяти (который выделяет память для программ). Так как происходит много просьб выделить память под вектора.